# It is difficult to understand the debugging step over of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

[Why can't the variable hallLamp be displayed?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxTn0.jpg)

Comment: Because that line of code has yet to execute. You are "before the line", not after it.

Answer (score 0):

Always add breakpoint on a next line after initialization of an object. In your case either step over to the next line or add breakpoint at line number 22.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).